# Pulling CiviCRM data into a custom Drupal module based on checksum/hash link

Tags: civicrm

I have a CiviCRM contribution page that allows an individual to renew a membership on behalf of an organization. When we email them from CiviMail with a checksum link to the page, it will prefill their information in the form automatically and have the membership renewal associate correctly to the organization.

How can I pull the organizational information into a custom Drupal module (e.g. a block that displays in the sidebar, for example)? I would like to have a text block that displays some information about the org and potentially names of people who are related to the org by relationships in CiviCRM. I won't have a problem doing that with Views and/or the CiviCRM API in a custom Drupal module, but I'm not sure how to get the org's ID in this scenario, to know which info to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to show the organization information of logged in contact.
So I would do following:

1. Get the contact id of logged in contact *(or anonymous user who used a checksum link, via the `cid` field in the URL, as @petednz noted)*.
2. Get the current employer id
3. then retrieve address of current employer

Comment: Since you are using a checksum, drupal considers the current user is 'anonymous'. So for any Views block using 'current user' for the contextual filter won't work. But the checksum url does provide the id=xx so a bit of php in your Views contextual filter could get you what you need

Comment: Thanks, both. The anonymous user case was what I was stumped on, and I've expanded that issue in a followup question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/140841/how-to-ensure-civicrm-checksum-cid-are-valid-in-custom-drupal-module